# Get Properties out of LogicalBinaryExpression ; How?

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda, .net-4.5

I would like to know if there is a way (and which is proper) to retrieves properties from a `LogicalBinaryExpression`, if it's possible.

I would like to have something like :

```
Dim whereClause as Expression(Of Func(Of Foo, Boolean)) = Function(f as Foo) f.ID = 1

Dim strignifiedWhereClause as string = Me.AMethodWhichhandlesThis(whereClause)
```

In the `AMethodWhichhandlesThis` methods, I would like to have something which get each properties to compare. If I get these, I'm fine with the rest of the code... this is really only the part of getting properties out of LogicalBinaryExpression! I even read somewhere that we should not do that at all but he never says... why, and how can I do this if it's not real?

Sorry for my english, I usually talk french.

Comment: Your example `strignifiedWhereClause` seems to imply that you want a string representation of the predicate expression. Is that what you want or do you want something else. Your phrase `each properties to compare` is unclear and could mean either the property types, the property getters, the property names ,... Could you include an example of the expected outcome of the `AMethodWhichhandlesThis`, and what you would do with this output.

Comment: You are right @alex, in fact, this fonction shall return a "where clause". I'll build it using attributes sets on my properties. But I can find a way to get these properties in a logicalbinaryexpression. I really just want to find a way to get associated properties or at least conditions related to my properties

Comment: As a string? If not, please [edit] your question to provide an example of the output and how you want to use the output.

Comment: As a string yes. But I must handles things in it to get an attribute which is set on each of my class' properties. These attributes have associated tables name related to my SQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract information from an expression it is recommend to use a custom visitor.

The following visitor will return `"Id = 1"` when you execute it with your expression :

```vb
Public Class WhereVisitor
    Inherits ExpressionVisitor

    Public Shared Function Stringify(expression As Expression) As String
        Dim visitor As New WhereVisitor()

        visitor.Visit(expression)

        Return visitor.Value
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        Me._value = New StringBuilder()
    End Sub

    Private _value As StringBuilder
    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return Me._value.ToString()
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function VisitBinary(node As BinaryExpression) As Expression
        ' node.Left and node.Right is not always of this type
        ' you have to check the type and maybe use another visitor 
        ' to obtain the information you want
        Dim left As MemberExpression = CType(node.Left, MemberExpression)
        Dim right As ConstantExpression = CType(node.Right, ConstantExpression)
        Me._value.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", left.Member.Name, right.Value))

        Return MyBase.VisitBinary(node)
    End Function

End Class
```

You can call it using :

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim whereClause As Expression(Of Func(Of Foo, Boolean)) = Function(f As Foo) f.Id = 1

    Dim s As String = WhereVisitor.Stringify(whereClause)

    Console.WriteLine(s)
End Sub
```

The `visitor` has to be modified to better fit your needs but you have a start point to implement what you want.